# ASP.NET application connecting to remote SQL Server using a unique active directory credential

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection

I will try and explain this unusual problem.

I have an ASP.NET web application which sits on the company's local sql server.
There is another remote server which has a Person_Detail table configured with enhanced security mode.
Unless I can access the remote server with Active Directory credentials, the rows and results of the query are returned with the data filled in with 'anonymous' and the underlying information is not available.

To retrieve the underlying data of this Person-Detail table a unique Active Directory User has been set up and has been placed in the Active Directory group on the remote server. Logging in to SSMS with this unique Active Directory User and querying the Person_Detail table displays the underlying information in this table.

When users are logged in to this ASP.NET application on the local server, they will be using their own Active Directory account. These users have a different Active Directory account to the unique Active Directory User that has been set up to access the Person_Detail on the remote server.

There will be many users that will need to log in to this ASP.NET web application and view the details of the Person_Detail table on the remote server, so making changes to anything on each of the PC's is not practical.

Does anyone know what I need to do in the connection string/IIS/etc.. of my ASP application/server to connect the ASP.NET application on our local server to the remote server using these unique Active Directory User details (and not the logged in user details)?